# Python3.4 general code for inserting data in MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, cursor

what I want to do is,

**1. Passing data to `store_db()` as a dictionary.**

**2. No matter what size the data is, it can store all datas to mySQL.**

```
def store_db(passwd, table_name, data, db_name='chois_crawl'):
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                                 user='root',
                                 password=passwd,
                                 db=db_name,
                                 charset='utf8',
                                 cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            all_keys = ', '.join(data.keys())
            sql = "INSERT INTO {table} ({all_keys}) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)".format(table=table_name, all_keys=all_keys)
            cursor.executemany(sql, data.values())
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

Problem:
1. This code doesn't work.
2. In `sql` string, I have to generalize the number of `%s` depending on the size of `data`.

Comment: Are you sure you can use `all_keys` without escaping?

Comment: sorry but what is escaping?